# Why do you save $s register into the stack when calling other functions in MIPS?

Tags: stack, mips, cpu-registers

I've read other questions in stackoverflow very similar to what I'm asking but I still do not understand. I understand the basic idea behind a stack and how it works but I still do not understand why you have to go to the trouble of saving the value that the $s register have before calling the function.

Like for example, consider this c code.

```
int main()
{
   int a = 5, b = 5, c = 0;
   int c = addNumbers(a,b);
}
```

in that example, I'm don't care about the value that c has initially, so why would care to save it? I'm only concern with the return value it gets from the function.

One example off the top of my head that could apply to why you would save $s registers into the stack is to save the value of the variables in main so that when you send those variables into a function, the value of those variables in main remain the same.

This make sense because that variable on one hand could be use as an argument in a function and then used in an if statement after returning from the function.
So in that situation you would want to preserve that value.

If some one could provide a better example, that would be great.

Comment: Your example isn't very realistic. It's also not a good analogy, because `c` is local to `main`, so `addNumbers` wouldn't be able to modify it (unless you e.g. pass a pointer to it). Anyway, it's just a convention that certain registers are _callee-saved_. That way, the _caller_ doesn't have to save them, and the _callee_ only has to save them if it modifies them. This is more efficient than always saving everything.

Comment: @Michael Could you provide an example of what would happen if you had multiple functions and never decided to save registers that were suppose to be saved? Maybe that would help.

Comment: I'd say the behaviour would be undefined. Consider for example if one of those registers held the base address of some data structure in memory, then another function sets the register to some other value, and then the first function tries to access the data structure. Just about anything could happen as a result of that, and you might not notice it immediately.

Comment: @Michael Alright that makes sense but let me give you another example. Suppose you have have an $s register set to zero in a label called main and along you the way you have an if statement(branch statement) to see if that register is greater than 10. In between that, you have a function that increase that register by some amount. Could be plus 10, 5 etc. Would you then save that register to the stack even though it's only set to zero(a default value you don't really care if it changes) and that the main purpose of that function is to increase the register?

Comment: You should use `$v0` and `$v1` to return integer results from functions. If you're never going to interact with any other code you can make up pretty much any convention you want, but otherwise you should follow some standard ABI (Application Binary Interface).

Comment: @Michael  Alright it's just I'm coming from another high-level programming language and some concepts in assembly language are a little hard for me to grasp at the moment but I'll get the hang of  it eventually.